# Bash Help with Until Loop

Tags: command-line, bash

Hoping you can point me in the right direction.
I have script that runs openvas via CLI.

Now you have to run another command to see the status of the jobs. The job total will always be different. E.g one day there will be 7 scans the next there will be 13.

I need the script to pause until all the outputs say Done.

See below the ouput from the command.

```
omp -u admin -w admin -h 127.0.01 -p 9390 -G
7ee0ef08-686e-4ad6-b826-08938fc8b694  Running 28%  192.168.0.10
fa7230f9-6367-4db6-8eb5-f6368375d577  Running 94%  192.168.0.23
fbc4e409-e72d-4749-861d-db60ed55693b  Done         192.168.0.25
9e0f2e40-2da4-4ef6-af6f-9ab8cfbf9902  Running  1%  192.168.0.252
492c7462-a75e-4d44-b5dc-5c9af27c9e07  Running  1%  192.168.0.253
```

In my bash script I am using the following

```
until omp -u admin -w admin -h 127.0.01 -p 9390 -G | grep "Done";
done
```

Now when the script gets to the "until" stage. I get the following error

```
./Pen-test-automation.sh: line 226: syntax error near unexpected token `Done'
./Pen-test-automation.sh: line 226: `Done'
```

Help please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `do some_command`:

```
until omp -u admin -w admin -h 127.0.01 -p 9390 -G | grep "Done"
do
    :
done
```

The colon, `:`, is just a no-op command.

#### Simpler example

Observe that this gives the error that you see:

```
$ until echo $RANDOM | grep 5; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

If we add, `do` and a place holder command, like `:`, then the loop runs properly:

```
$ until echo $RANDOM | grep 5; do : ; done
15857
```

Comment: Hi Unfortunately, this did not work.
The Openvas command ran as normal created all the tasks and then completely skipped the
 until omp -u admin -w admin -h 127.0.01 -p 9390 -G | grep "Done"
do
    :
done

Comment: @AlexHarding If the `until` loop was _"completely skipped"_, how did the `omp` command run?

Comment: The loop runs after the openvas command. Im checking the status of the running openvas scans and dont want the script to continue until they all say done.

However i dont think its going to work how I want it to, so I may have to monitor the service until that quits and then continue.

Any idea how I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexHarding OK.  While I hope that my answer here has gotten rid of the "unexpected token" bash error,  it sounds like you now have a question about Openvas.  Unfortunately, Openvas is outside of my experience.  You may want to open another question and make it specifically about monitoring Openvas.  Good luck.